# 'Unsupported browser' when accessing router page

Tags: java, android

Today, I wanted to make an app that accesses the router's web page to make managing it easier. However, my router said that [the web browser that I'm using is unsupported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMNgg.jpg).

Here's the activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private TextView textView;



    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("192.168.1.1");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            //API Level under 24
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url){
                return false;
            }

            //API Level over 24
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }
        });


        urlBar();
        debugFinish();
    }


    public void debugFinish() {
        Log.d("MyApplication", "Finishing in 5 seconds.");
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Log.d("MyApplication", "Finishing in 4 seconds."),1000);
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Log.d("MyApplication", "Finishing in 3 seconds."),2000);
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Log.d("MyApplication", "Finishing in 2 seconds."),3000);
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Log.d("MyApplication", "Finishing in 1 second."),4000);
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "Finished.");
            finish();
        },5000);
    }

    public void urlBar() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
            textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(webUrl);
            urlBar();
        },100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the logs for the latest session:

```
08/23 18:19:57: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-A528B.
Install successfully finished in 325 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.censored.censored/com.censored.censored.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.censored.censored
Connected to process 24423 on device 'samsung-sm_a528b-serialshoudbehere'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
V/studio.deploy: Startup agent attached to VM
V/studio.deploy: No existing instrumentation found. Loading instrumentation from instruments-1f2f27f8.jar
W/outerpageacces: DexFile /data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.studio/instruments-1f2f27f8.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
V/studio.deploy: Applying transforms with cached classes
W/outerpageacces: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
W/outerpageacces: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication()++ app=com.censored.censored
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10759; state: ENABLED
W/ActivityThread: Application com.censored.censored is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
Connecting to com.censored.censored
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
V/studio.deploy: Startup agent attached to VM
V/studio.deploy: No existing instrumentation found. Loading instrumentation from instruments-1f2f27f8.jar
W/outerpageacces: DexFile /data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.studio/instruments-1f2f27f8.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
V/studio.deploy: Applying transforms with cached classes
W/outerpageacces: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
W/outerpageacces: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication()++ app=com.censored.censored
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10759; state: ENABLED
W/ActivityThread: Application com.censored.censored is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:59305', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1429)
W/ActivityThread: Slow operation: 2612ms so far, now at handleBindApplication: Before HardwareRenderer
W/ActivityThread: Slow operation: 2621ms so far, now at handleBindApplication: After HardwareRenderer
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~as9uWR63HKmuwYZvqPYU3Q==/com.censored.censored-0ouQJlouEDKWFYvo3am4mg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~as9uWR63HKmuwYZvqPYU3Q==/com.censored.censored-0ouQJlouEDKWFYvo3am4mg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.censored.censored' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Updatable production driver is not supported on the device.
D/LoadedApk: LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext.mOpPackageName=com.censored.censored appContext.mBasePackageName=com.censored.censored
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication() --
D/OpenGLRenderer: RenderThread::requireGlContext()
I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : cac6e6f805, I5187d04b75
    Build Date                       : 11/22/21
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.35.01.10
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
I/AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
I/AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016dc094, ME: 0x00000000
D/OpenGLRenderer: RenderThread::setGrContext()
I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@ad5ddd0[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowControllerCallback=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false
D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@ad5ddd0[]
I/DecorView: getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=450 msg=resources_loaded
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~YgYDZv4GpC9wYpwxXiO9DA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary.dev_524300233-fAGblpk31Yjy1vkpqWEHyA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~YgYDZv4GpC9wYpwxXiO9DA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary.dev_524300233-fAGblpk31Yjy1vkpqWEHyA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/outerpageacces: Entry not found
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview.dev version 106.0.5243.2 (code 524300233)
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/cr_WVCFactoryProvider: Loaded version=106.0.5243.2 minSdkVersion=29 isBundle=true multiprocess=true packageId=2
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Successfully loaded native library
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder: Flushed 9 samples from 9 histograms.
E/SchedPolicy: Failed to find cgroup for tid 24423
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_32.bin': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/icudtl.dat': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/chrome_100_percent.pak': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/resources.pak': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
W/chromium: [WARNING:dns_config_service_android.cc(115)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10759; state: ENABLED
W/outerpageacces: Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_32.bin': No such file or directory
E/outerpageacces: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.censored.censored/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
W/cr_media: BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission is missing.
W/cr_media: registerBluetoothIntentsIfNeeded: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
D/MyApplication: Finishing in 5 seconds.
D/NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::BpCustomFrequencyManager()
I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=true
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@ad5ddd0 TM=true
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=6 res=0x7 s={true -5476376616297765184} ch=true fn=-1
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:11420 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4193 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2919 
D/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: Creating frameDrawingCallback nextDrawUseBlastSync=false reportNextDraw=true hasBlurUpdates=false
D/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: Creating frameCompleteCallback
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface
D/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: Received frameDrawingCallback frameNum=1. Creating transactionCompleteCallback=false
I/BufferQueueProducer: [ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]#0(BLAST Consumer)0](id:5f6700000000,api:1,p:24423,c:24423) queueBuffer: queued for the first time.
D/OpenGLRenderer: GPIS:: SetUp Pid : 24423    Tid : 24468
D/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: Received frameCompleteCallback  lastAcquiredFrameNum=1 lastAttemptedDrawFrameNum=1
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$addFrameCompleteCallbackIfNeeded$3$ViewRootImpl:4995 android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: [DP] rdf()
D/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: reportDrawFinished (fn: -1) 
D/InsetsSourceConsumer: ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR on com.censored.censored/com.censored.censored.MainActivity
D/InsetsSourceConsumer: ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_STATUS_BAR on com.censored.censored/com.censored.censored.MainActivity
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
D/MyApplication: Finishing in 4 seconds.
D/MyApplication: Finishing in 3 seconds.
D/MyApplication: Finishing in 2 seconds.
D/MyApplication: Finishing in 1 second.
I/outerpageacces: Compiler allocated 4564KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
D/MyApplication: Finished.
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=214
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=true visible=false
D/OpenGLRenderer: setSurface called with nullptr
D/OpenGLRenderer: setSurface() destroyed EGLSurface
D/OpenGLRenderer: destroyEglSurface
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=8 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true fn=55
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
D/OpenGLRenderer: setSurface called with nullptr
I/ViewRootImpl@437d938[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: '3e2bfbb', fd=175
D/OpenGLRenderer: setSurface called with nullptr
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

In case you are wondering: yes. The page opens just fine in the Chrome app on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This did the trick